# Mapping array of objects into new array of array by value

Tags: ios, swift

Hey i have array of objects, my goal is to split them into several arrays by common property value for example:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let city: String
}

let persons: [Person] = [Person(name: "John", city: "San Francisco"),
                         Person(name: "Tim", city: "San Francisco"),
                         Person(name: "Bob", city: "Atlanta")]
```

my goal is to get arrays that contain only persons from same city.
In that example result will be two arrays first contain John and Tim's objects, and 2nd contain only Bob's object.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you should use a `dictionary` and group items by the `city` property:

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: persons) { $0.city }
```

If you don't need the keys, then you can map them on values like:

```
let groupedWOKeys = grouped.map { $1 }
```